# Logging a user in Spring Cloud Gateway with SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

**What I do ty?**
Hi folks, i'm trying to create a gateway (with Spring cloud gateway and Spring boot 3.0.0) that manages authentication and authorisation of routes.

**What is my problem?**
The problem I have is that I'm using springSecurityFilterChain and I can't get anything to run before this filter, so I can't authenticate a user if he wants to acces a private route.

**What do I want?**
I want to know how I can authenticate a user before it goes through the filterChain (I've alredy tried many things I've seen in forums, posts, etc. and I have not been able to do it :/).

**My code**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebfluxSecurityConfig{

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(Routes.PUBLIC_ROUTES).permitAll()    //Public routes
        .pathMatchers(Routes.AUTH_ROUTES).authenticated(); //Authenticate routes
 
        return http.build();
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to authenticate a user before the springSecurityFilterChain in Spring Cloud Gateway, currently I have not been able to do so as I have not been able to place any filter to authenticate before the filter chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create user to do that. See the sample attached in below. I am using in-memory user to authenticate. Note in-memory user is just for testing purpose only.

https://github.com/DeepuGeorgeJacob/school-management/blob/main/security/in-memory-user-security/src/main/java/com/school/management/config/InMemoryUserSecurityAdapter.java

```
@Configuration
public class InMemoryUserSecurityAdapter {

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/school-library-service/**").authenticated()
            .and().authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager())
            .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll().and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .build();
}

@Bean
ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager(){
    return new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(getInMemoryUserDetails());
}

@Bean
public MapReactiveUserDetailsService getInMemoryUserDetails() {
    UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin1").password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
    return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(admin);
}
```

}

To log the events try this `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` in your properties file

Happy coding :)